# Check a radio button by default with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, forms, function, radio-button

in an html page that I use to display text snippets, I use jQuery to filter those that contain just text, text including some url links or both :

JS code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').attr('checked', false);
  $(".selection").on("change", ":radio", function() {
    var checkedVal = parseInt($(this).filter(":checked").val(), 10);
    $(".container").hide().filter(function() {
      if (checkedVal === 2) {
        return $(this).find('a[href]').length && $(this)
      } else if (checkedVal === 1) {
        return $(this).find('a[href]').length <= 0 && $(this)
      } else {
        return $(this)
      }
    }).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selection">
  </button> Display : <input type="radio" name="check" value="1" /> Texts only | <input type="radio" name="check" value="2" /> Texts w/ links | <input type="radio" name="check" value="-1" checked="checked" /> Texts + Texts w/ links</div>
```

I would like the "Texts + Texts w/ links" button to be checked by default and this choice to be kept when the page is refreshed.

I don't know how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Just add the `checked` attribute to the default button. And get rid of the JavaScript that unchecks all the buttons.

Comment: I have removed the line $('input[type=radio]').attr('checked', false); and added checked="checked" and none of the button are working.

Comment: Why are you using filter here? `$(this).filter(":checked").val()` That's not the way to get the selected button. The correct way is `$(".selection :radio:checked").val()`

Comment: By using the correct way and adding the attribute checked="checked", the button is not checked by default.

Comment: It should be checked by default unless something else is unchecking it.

Comment: It is checked for a short time when the page is loading..

Comment: Something else is unchecking it. When I comment out the line `$('input[type=radio]').attr('checked', false);` the default button stays checked.

Comment: You can use an attribute modification breakpoint in DevTools to find out what's doing it.

Comment: It works ! How to ensure that when refreshing the page, if we have checked another button, that the default button is checked again ?

Comment: That should happen automatically. I suspect you have code that's saving selections in a cookie or local storage so it can restore the selection. Or maybe the form processing code is doing this.  You need to find that code and remove it.

Comment: I don't see anything other than the form processing code.

Comment: If it's checked briefly, there must be JavaScript unchecking it.

Comment: When refreshing the page, the last button to have been checked is checked.

Comment: When you do `View Source`, does that button have `checked="checked"`? If so, it's being done by the server.

Comment: No the last buton doesn't have checked="checked".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of unchecking all the buttons, check the one you want to be the default.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selection :radio[value=-1]').attr('checked', true);
  $(".selection").on("change", ":radio", function() {
    var checkedVal = parseInt($(".selection :radio:checked").val(), 10);
    $(".container").hide().filter(function() {
      if (checkedVal === 2) {
        return $(this).find('a[href]').length && $(this)
      } else if (checkedVal === 1) {
        return $(this).find('a[href]').length <= 0 && $(this)
      } else {
        return $(this)
      }
    }).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selection">
  </button> Display : <input type="radio" name="check" value="1" /> Texts only | <input type="radio" name="check" value="2" /> Texts w/ links | <input type="radio" name="check" value="-1" checked="checked" /> Texts + Texts w/ links</div>
```